# Does Electron have a "toolbar" window type on OSX?

Tags: javascript, electron

Does `Electron` have a 'toolbar' style window? I thought it did from experiments I did a few years ago but I'm not seeing it in the docs for [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window).

> On macOS, possible types are **desktop**, **textured**.
>
> The textured type adds metal gradient appearance (NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask).
>
> The desktop type places the window at the desktop background window level 
>   (kCGDesktopWindowLevel - 1). Note that desktop window
>   will not receive focus, keyboard or mouse events, but you can use
>   globalShortcut to receive input sparingly.

I'm looking to create a "tool" window like below (from the `Preview.app`) with the skinny window bar.

[image]

Comment: I don't use macOS as my main OS so I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding this. To me it seems like you're looking for the [`titleBarStyle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) option?